# How many degrees of freedom does a tetragon with rotary joints exhibit?

Tags: geometry, statistics

Given is:

Cartesian space: point $A = (0, 0)$, point $B = (x_b, 0)$, point $C = (x_c, y_c)$, point $D = (x_d, y_d)$

The constant distance $AB$, same $BC$, same $CD$, same $DA$

Find:

How many of the numbers $(x_b, x_c, y_c, x_d, y_d)$ need to be known in order to know exactly the state of the system? As in, how many degrees of freedom does the system have?

Or is the problem in the title even well represented inside the body of the question?

Comment: If I understand your setup, the point $B$ is either fixed or one has a discrete degree of freedom to choose $x_b$ to be on the positive or negative $x$-axis.  Another word for "tetragon" is "quadrilateral".

Comment: @hardmath I have no idea what I am doing! I am fixing the coordinate system to coincide with the first link (vector y coincides with link AB). I don't know am I allowed to do it.

Comment: Depending on what your intended application is, this could be a good approach.  When you start with the length of the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$, fixing the point $A$ to be the origin reduces the degrees of freedom, and also rotating the first link $AB$ to be on the $x$-axis reduces the degrees of freedom.  If you are doing some kind of programming, this might be exactly what you want to do.  I was just pointing out that in this setup the link from $A$ to $B$ could be either in the positive direction or the negative direction along the $x$-axis keeping a constant distance.

Comment: Do you mean that $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$ are known and fixed? Because then $AB$ determines $x_b$ in this setup. Or do you mean that the four lenghts should all be equal?

Comment: Note that if you know $x_b$ and $x_c$ there will usually be two possible values of $y_c$, two values of $x_d$ (one of which is the degenerate $x_b$) and three  of $y_d$ (which one determined by $y_c$ and $x_d$).  So even if these are not fixed, their freedom is severely limited